# Making visible lifebars via checking for colision in python 3.5 tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use check for collision tricks for tkinter. (I don't use pygame) but I need a visible life bar that can change colours. Here's my script:

```
#Tkinter loader
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
window.title ('VOID')
c = Canvas (window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg= 'black')
c.pack()
ship_id = c.create_polygon (5, 5, 5,  25, 25, 25, 25, 5,  fill='white')
SHIP_R = 25
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2
c.move (ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
# Movment control
SHIP_SPD = 10
def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysym == 'w':
    c.move (ship_id, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysym == 's':
    c.move (ship_id, 0, SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysym == 'a':
    c.move (ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'd':
        c.move (ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
c.bind_all ('<Key>', move_ship)
# Spawning system (needs copying)
from random import randint
bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()
MIN_BUB_R = 20
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 20
GAP = 100
def create_bubble():
x = WIDTH + GAP
Y = randint (0, HEIGHT)
r = randint (MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
id1 = c.create_polygon (5, 5, 5,  25, 25, 25, 25, 5,  fill='lime')
bub_id.append(id1)
bub_r.append(r)
bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))

def move_bubbles():
for i in range(len(bub_id)):
    c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)


from time import sleep, time
BUB_CHANCE = 10
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while True:
if randint (1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
    create_bubble()
move_bubbles()
window.update()
sleep(0.01)
```

With the fact that both lifebars will go up and down, but at different rates. (so that health takes smaller steps than level.) also with a system were if health or level go to 0 or 100 precent, than something happens like steps. (so you go down a level if the level bar goes to low, and go up a  level with the background changing with the lifebar levels.) and the colour will pulse depending on the level you are at. 
Thanks.

Comment: You've told us what you are doing but you haven't asked a question. What part of the problem do you need help with? What have you done to try to solve this problem?

Comment: Making a Lifebar that can be seen by the player. Like [this.](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=I6NAeeqC&id=6524B6209931E3D77DEB8F6126970EB151C59E53&thid=OIP.I6NAeeqC_-kCT20grnjcKQEsC7&q=bit.trip+beat&simid=608012047616509770&selectedindex=15&mode=overlay&first=1) were they both go up and down, but take differently sized steps to 0. the book I'm using does have a Points counter, but that is a number, and I want 2 bars.